# Getting error while debugging in react native?

Tags: react-native, debugging

i am trying to debug my react native app but getting following error.
[image]

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_PROTOCOL]: Protocol "localhost:" not supported. Expected "http:". Debugging won't work: Try reloading the JS from inside the app, or Reconnect the VS Code debugger: Couldn't import script at <localhost:8081/Users/sandesh/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/85B2AD76-7F82-48EC-AF36-B10C5DE8E783/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B7545C06-A275-410D-9C57-C62B1931AF3C/eRamp.app/bundle/index.ios.jsbundle> (error code 1408)
```

launch.json is as bellow

```
 "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    
        {
            "name": "Debug iOS ete",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "ios",

            "env": {
                "ENVFILE": ".env.ete"
            }
        },

        {
            "name": "Debug Android ete",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "type": "reactnative",
            "request": "launch",
            "platform": "android",
            
            "env": {
                "ENVFILE": ".env.ete"
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

**To enable debugging in react native,**
If you are in **emulator** press Ctrl + M or if in your **device** just shake it, a dialog box will appear where you will see Debug option, just press it and you'll automatically be redirected to your web browser.
Press **Ctrl + Shift + I** to start debugging.

Comment: @pritik Thanks for help..but even after CTR + M or shaking dialog box is not coming  app  is just stuck on launch screen